# Oberver.next() is not a function

Tags: javascript, rxjs, settimeout

I want to print *hello world*

```
 const obs = new Observable( (observer)=>{ setTimeout(observer.next, 0) } );
 obs.subscribe(()=>{console.log("world")});
 console.log("hello ");
```

This gives an error **this._next is not a function**

If I instead write the following it works fine:

```
 const obs = new Observable( (observer)=>{ setTimeout(()=>{observer.next()}, 0) } );
 obs.subscribe(()=>{console.log("world")});
 console.log("hello ");
```

Why can't I pass the reference to observer.next callback directly to setTimeout()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RXJS the internals of the `.next()` function use `this`. To get a better understanding, the `next` method is defined [like so](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/2947583bb33e97f3db9e6d9f6cea70c62a173060/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L126C1-L126C1):

```js
next(value: T): void {
  if (this.isStopped) {
    handleStoppedNotification(nextNotification(value), this);
  } else {
    this._next(value!);
  }
}
```

The value of `this` inside of this method depends on how it is called (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work-and-when-should-it-be-used) for more info). When you call it using:

```js
observer.next()
```

as you do in your second example, the `this` value gets set to the `observer` object you called the `next` method on, allowing it to function correctly when the internals eventually end up calling `._next()` on the `observer` object. However, when you pass the `next` function reference to `setTimeout()` in your first example:

```js
setTimeout(observer.next, 0)
```

you lose the `this` context (that being the `observer`), as now you're just passing the function reference of `next` to `setTimeout()`, and not calling the method on a particular object anymore. When `setTimeout()` eventually invokes the `next` function after the specified delay, it doesn't have any information about where the function it's calling came from, and so the `this` value inside of the `next` method once its invoked defaults to the [global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object), or undefined in strict mode, which both don't have `_next()` methods.

An alternative would be to [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the observable to the function, which returns a new function with the `this` value set explicitly to the `observable`:

```js
setTimeout(observer.next.bind(observer), 0)
```